# java.io.StreamCorruptedException with ruby sender and java client

Tags: java, ruby, objectinputstream

I have a ruby program that writes data to a socket with sock.write, and I'm reading the data with ObjectInputStream in a java file. I'm getting an invalid header error that translate to the first few characters of my stream.

I've read that if you use ObjectInputStream you must write with ObjectOutputStream, but since the writing file is in ruby im not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

As you say, `ObjectInputStream` assumes that the bytes it's receiving have been formatted by an `ObjectOutputStream`. That is, it is expecting the incoming bytes to be a specific representation of a Java primitive or object.

Your Ruby code is unlikely to format bytes in such a way.

You need to define exactly the byte format of the message passing from the Ruby to the Java process. You could tell us more about that message format, but it's likely you will need to use Java's ByteArrayInputStream (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html). The data will come into the Java program as a raw array of bytes, and you will need to parse/unpack/process these bytes into whatever objects are appropriate.

Unless performance is critical, you'd probably be best off using JSON or YAML as the intermediate format. They would make it simple to send simple objects such as strings, arrays, and hashes (maps).